# How can I create a guid in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, guid

I need to be able to create guids on the fly.  Is there a way to do that in MFC?  I see how to do it in .net, but we haven't gone there yet.  If not, do you have pointers to some code I can use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
GUID guid;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateGuid(&guid); 

// Convert the GUID to a string
_TUCHAR * guidStr;
UuidToString(&guid, &guidStr);
```

The application is responsible for calling `RpcStringFree` to deallocate the memory allocated for the string returned in the StringUuid parameter.

Answer (score 13):

```
   //don't forget to add Rpcrt4.lib to your project

    CString m_ListID(L"error");
    RPC_WSTR guidStr;
    GUID guid;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateGuid(&guid);
    if (hr == S_OK)
    {
        if(UuidToString(&guid, &guidStr) == RPC_S_OK)
        {
            m_ListID = (LPTSTR)guidStr;
            RpcStringFree(&guidStr);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the COM function CoCreateGuid, e.g.:

```
GUID guid;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateGuid(&guid);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the function UuidCreate to generate GUIDs :

```
UUID generated;

if (::UuidCreate(&generated) != RPC_S_OK)
throw std::exception(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this sample

```
WCHAR       GuidText[250] ={0};
UUID        uuid;

CoCreateGuid (&uuid);
wsprintf(
        GuidText,
        L"%08X-%04X-%04X-%02X%02X-%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
        uuid.Data1,
        uuid.Data2,
        uuid.Data3,
        uuid.Data4[0], uuid.Data4[1],
        uuid.Data4[2], uuid.Data4[3], uuid.Data4[4], uuid.Data4[5], uuid.Data4[6], uuid.Data4[7]
        );
```